# google docs api - trouble creating single paragraph with multiple text styles like bold, italic, etc

Tags: google-docs-api

So I have gotten comfortable with the google docs API, but I am still having one problem. When I try to mix styles like bold and italic into a single paragraph, the styles are not displaying correctly.

Instead when I set to bold and italic, the span of text is reverting to Areal font type (which is different than what I have set) and then continuing for the rest of the paragraph: [image: it looks like this]

The strange thing is, if I add a simple line break before and after the request it will work just fine. I can have one paragraph regular text, followed by bold, followed by regular, followed by italic:

[image]

But when I don't add the line break, it doesn't work correctly. I think it may be an index issue (although I'm taking the suggested approach of building the document backward with request so indexing really shouldn't be the problem, I'm not dealing with it directly. )

It could also be that I'm including paragraph styles with each textstyle update request, maybe its conflicting with something?

Or maybe what I am trying to do is actually not yet supported? It is v.1 of the api after all.

The fn I'm using to make the requests:

```
function textRequest(text: string, fontSize: number, alignment = 'CENTER', lineSpacing = 100, color = 0.3, style = ' '){
  const requests:Array<object> = [
    {
      insertText: {
        text: text,
        location: {
          index: 1,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      updateParagraphStyle: {           
        paragraphStyle: {
          lineSpacing: lineSpacing,
          namedStyleType: 'NORMAL_TEXT',
          alignment: alignment,
          direction: 'LEFT_TO_RIGHT'
        },
        fields: 'namedStyleType, alignment, direction, lineSpacing',
        range: {
          startIndex: 1,
          endIndex: text.length + 1,
        },
      }
    },
    {
      updateTextStyle: {
        textStyle: {
          bold: style === 'BOLD',
          italic: style === 'ITALIC',
          foregroundColor: {
            color: {
              rgbColor: {
                red: color,
                green: color,
                blue: color
              }
            }
          },
          fontSize: {
            magnitude: fontSize,
            unit: 'PT'
          },
          weightedFontFamily: {
            fontFamily: 'PT',
            weight: 400
          }
        },
        fields: 'bold, italic, foregroundColor, fontSize, weightedFontFamily',
        range: {
          startIndex: 1,
          endIndex: text.length + 1,
        },
      },
 
    }
  ];
  return requests;
}
```

then I'm building the full request by pushing calls like this:

```
request.push(textRequest(text.trim(), 12, 'START', 200, 0.3, 'BOLD')
```

Anyway, all thoughts or suggestings are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the same request in both the working and non-working scenarios, or do you make any changes?

Comment: yeah exactly the same, the only difference is when it's working I make another request in between with just '\n' as the text. They all use the same fn just with different params passed in.

Comment: I also tried another request similar to the new line approach, but with just a blank string like '  ' passed in, but that didn't work. It still defaulted to the areal font.

Comment: Which is your expected output situation in your showing 2 images? If those were not your expected situation, can you provide your expected situation?

Comment: @Tanaike it's hard to tell, but the first image is not actually bold. It is just changing the font style to areal. I want like the first image but with the text bold. 

In the second image you can see when the text is bold, but then it has to be separate lines.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the goal of your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: no problem, the goal is to change some text to bold in the middle of the paragraph.

Comment: or some text to italic in the middle of the paragraph. Right now, trying to make bold or italic does not work. It changes the text to Areal font.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when a paragraph of `sample1 sample2 sample3` is put to Google Document using Docs API, you want to set the bold type to `sample2`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, or sample 1 or sample 3. But I want all the same paragraph.

Comment: maybe sample 1 normal text, sample 2 bold, sample 3 italic.. I cannot find why my code above is not working.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Question 1

I believe your goal is as follows.

- For example, when a paragraph of `sample1 sample2 sample3` is put to Google Document using Docs API, you want to set the bold type to `sample2`.

When I saw your request body, at `updateTextStyle`, `range` is `{startIndex: 1, endIndex: text.length + 1,}`. In this case, this text style is reflected in the whole `text`. I think that this might be the reason for your issue. If you want to set the bold to the part of the text in a paragraph, it is required to set the part of the text to `range`.

Here, I would like to introduce a simple sample request body as follows. When a paragraph of `sample1 sample2 sample3` with the bold type to `sample2` is put to Google Document using Docs API, the sample request body is as follows.

#### Sample request body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample1 sample2 sample3",
        "location": {
          "index": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "textStyle": {
          "bold": true
        },
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 9,
          "endIndex": 16
        },
        "fields": "bold"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- When you use this request body to the batchUpdate method of Docs API, the following result is obtained. Also, you can simply test this request body at [Try this method](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate).

  [image]

#### Reference:

- [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetextstylerequest)

### Question 2

From your following new question,

> is there a way to accomplish the same thing, but with 3 SEPARATE insertText requests? So.. sample 1 is first request with style normal, sample 2 is second request with style bold, and sample 3 is normal again.

Unfortunately, I think that these process cannot be achieve by 3 requests. Because, at the batchUpdate method of Google Docs API, `insertText` and `updateTextStyle` cannot be inlcuded one batch request. In this case, it is required to separate them for each request. So, in order to achieve your new question, it is required to use the following request body.

#### Sample request body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample1 ",
        "location": {
          "index": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample2 ",
        "location": {
          "index": 9
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "textStyle": {
          "bold": true
        },
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 9,
          "endIndex": 16
        },
        "fields": "bold"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample3",
        "location": {
          "index": 17
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- When this request body is run, the same result with the above image is obtained.

### Question 3

From your following reply,

> In my example I am trying to build the document in reverse so the index will always = 1. And the endIndex should always = text.length + 1. I do this because I do not know every start/endIndex for bold or italic. The request needs to be build dynamically.

From your 1st and 2nd question, I couldn't understand you wanted that. For example, if you want to put the values `sample3`, `sample2` and `sample1` in order. And you want to set the bold to `sample2`.

In this case, how about the following sample request body?

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample3",
        "location": {
          "index": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample2 ",
        "location": {
          "index": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "textStyle": {
          "bold": true
        },
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 8
        },
        "fields": "bold"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample1 ",
        "location": {
          "index": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 8
        },
        "fields": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this request body, when `sample1` is put, it is required to use the default text style. Because when this is not used, `sample1` is set as the bold type by the text style of `sample2`. Please be careful this.

About your following 3rd question,

> I still do not understand why I cannot make updateStyle request after updateText request. This way I always know the start and endIndex will be correct.

In my sample request body of your 2nd question, I don't use `updateText`. When you miscopied `updateText` with `insertText`, when both `insertText` and `updateTextStyle` are used in one request, an error of `Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'updateTextStyle'` occurs. So, I think that this is the current specification of the Google side. So, the answer of your 3rd question of `why I cannot make updateStyle request after insertText request` is due to the current specification of the Google side.

Comment: is there a way to accomplish the same thing, but with 3 SEPARATE insertText requests? So.. sample 1 is first request with style normal, sample 2 is second request with style bold, and sample 3 is normal again.

Comment: @Louis Sankey About your new question, I added an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: thank you for reply.  In my example I am trying to build the document in reverse so the index will always = 1. And the endIndex should always = text.length + 1. I do this because I do not know every start/endIndex for bold or italic. The request needs to be build dynamically. I still do not understand why I cannot make updateStyle request after updateText request. This way I always know the start and endIndex will be correct.

Comment: @Louis Sankey Thank you for replying. About your 3rd question, I added one more answer in my answer. Could you please confirm it? I think that the answer of your 3rd question of `why I cannot make updateStyle request after insertText request` is due to the current specification of the Google side. I deeply apologize for this specification. If my answer for your 3rd question was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your third answer is what I am trying, but for me it is not working. Instead of making the text bold, it is removing the all the formatting, and making the text Areal.

Comment: @Louis Sankey Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your new issue of `Your third answer is what I am trying, but for me it is not working. Instead of making the text bold, it is removing the all the formatting, and making the text Areal.`, I think that the reason of it is due to `"fields": "*"`. So, how about changing this? But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. Because your question has already been 3rd question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: Hi thank you for your patience. I have found the cause of the problem, but I do not know the solution. The problem is that need to always be updating the textStyle AND the paragraphStyle for each request. In my code I have the paragraphStyle request BETWEEN insertText and updateTextStyle - this is causing the problem with the bold, italic not working correctly. But when I try to put paragraphStyle AFTER, then it has no effect. So I need to figure out the correct order to make everything work.

Comment: @Louis Sankey Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand your current situation. Because your question has already been 3rd question and more. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? Although I could resolve your initial question, unfortunately, I cannot resolve your new question because I cannot understand your current situation.

Comment: @Louis Sankey By this, I cannot think of a solution to your new question. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. Now, I think that it is required to correctly understand the current situation of your new question. So, can you explain the detail of it? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. I think that I have to study more and more.

Comment: @Louis Sankey I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation from `I have found the cause of the problem, but I do not know the solution. The problem is that need to always be updating the textStyle AND the paragraphStyle for each request. In my code I have the paragraphStyle request BETWEEN insertText and updateTextStyle - this is causing the problem with the bold, italic not working correctly. But when I try to put paragraphStyle AFTER, then it has no effect. So I need to figure out the correct order to make everything work.`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244804/discussion-between-louis-sankey-and-tanaike).